# Insert large number of rows without attaching the entities to the Persistence Context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

While streaming over a "data provider" I need to insert a fairly large number of entities in the database, say around 100.000. This whole step needs to be transactional.
To simplify my use-case as much as possible let's assume this is my code:

```
@Transactional
public void execute() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        carRespository.save(new Car());
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is that even if it's clear i have no use for the Car entities after the insert query is generated the entity **is attached to the Persistence Context** and held in memory until the transaction is done.
I would like to make sure that in case the garbage collection is triggered the created entities are cleared. For this currently I see two solutions:

- create a native insert query on the repository
- Inject the `EntityManager` in the service and call `em.detach(car)` after every insert

I tend to prefer the second option as I would not have to manage the native insert statement as the entity changes.

Can you confirm I taking the correct approach or suggest a better alternative?

Answer (score 2):

You can find in the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html) the way to insert the batch of data.

> When making new objects persistent flush() and then clear() the session regularly in order to control the size of the first-level cache.

Thus the following approach is recommended:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
    session.save(new Car());
    if (i%20 == 0 ) {
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}

tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Comment: This would be the "pure" Hibernate way of implementing my second suggestion (the one with detach). I acknowledge the your suggestion is clearing the entities "once in a while". I could also achieve  this with `em.clear()` .

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [`saveAndFlush(S entity)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#saveAndFlush-S-) method from spring data JPA [`JpaRepository`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html) instead of `save()`

Comment: From what i understand this will flush the insert to the db on the spot. I have no problem with that part : from my point of view this can be a single insert or a batch insert. What i'm interested is what is the best way to make sure the entities are available for gc.